# ASP.NET Core Web API (RESTful) Model Naming Convention backed by SQL Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project, whose template is tailored for RESTful services. In my DB instance, I have a SQL table called `Organizations` and a view based on that table called `Organizations_v`. In the .NET project, I created a model under the `Models` folder called `Organization`. The model will be backed by the SQL view.

As this an API, I don't really have any pages/views. It's not a true ASP.NET Core MVC application in that sense, right? But convention says if your model is backed by multiple tables, the model class name should end with `ViewModel`.

What's the proper naming convention for the model class for my use case? Since I'm using a SQL view to back the model, should I name the model class `OrganizationViewModel` or `Organization`?

Comment: A [View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064316/2030565) is simply a "model" used by the page View.

Comment: In the past, I have simply named the entity model the same as the database object (table or view).

Answer (score 3):

The following is a pretty standard naming convention I've both used and consumed:

Using your example of `Organizations`:

`Organization` - represents your business entity: the entity you are pulling out of the db.

`OrganizationModel` - represents the entity you *expose* via your api.

It is crucial to have this separation *from the very beginning*. The fallout from not having this separation will haunt you, trust me. For example, if you have to change the entity (and you will) you are forced to release a new version of your api.

Comment: That makes too much sense. So, instead of naming the entity exposed to the API  `OrganizationDTO`, in your example, you named it `OrganizationModel`. And since there's no concept of page or view in the API template, we wouldn't use the `ViewModel` naming convention.